# JavaScript filter data by week day and timestamps

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

In my personal project, users can define times when they want not to be disturbed. These times include the days of the week you selected, as well as the start and end timestamps of the interval.

Basically, on those days of the week and during these intervals stipulated by users, I cannot create tasks. That is, the "final" array should only contain the users that are readable for creating the tasks.

My current code is as follows:

```js
const data = [
    {
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        schedules: [
            {
                days: ['Tue', 'Wed', 'Fri'],
                start: '2022-01-07T10:50:00.859Z',
                end: '2022-01-07T11:30:00.859Z',
            },
            {
                days: ['Mon'],
                start: '2022-01-07T13:30:00.859Z',
                end: '2022-01-07T14:30:00.859Z',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Aaron',
        lastName: 'Park',
        schedules: [
            {
                days: ['Wed', 'Fri'],
                start: '2022-01-07T13:30:00.859Z',
                end: '2022-01-07T14:30:00.859Z',
            },
            {
                days: ['Mon'],
                start: '2022-01-07T13:30:00.859Z',
                end: '2022-01-07T14:30:00.859Z',
            },
        ],
    },
];

const todayWeekDay = new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', { weekday: 'short' });
const currentTime = new Date();

const filteredData = data.filter((user) => {
    const filteredSchedules = user.schedules.filter((schedule) => {
        const days = schedule.days;
        if (days.includes(todayWeekDay)) {
            const startTime = new Date(schedule.start);
            const endTime = new Date(schedule.end);
            if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
    if (filteredSchedules.length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

console.log(filteredData)
```

I haven't tested many edge cases yet, but I've noticed that sometimes when I "play" with the days of the week, sometimes the user should appear in the "final" array, but it doesn't.

In the final result, the user must be returned under the following circumstances:

- if the user has no schedules
- if the current week day is not in the days array
- if the current week day is in the days array, the user must be returned if the current time is not between the two timestamps (in these two timestamps I only care about hours and minutes)

The output I expect may change depending on the current day of the week and the hours.But for example, if today were the 21st of January 2022, which corresponds to a Friday. Between 10:50 am and 11:30 am, the result should be as follows:

```js
[{
  "firstName": "Aaron",
  "lastName": "Park",
  "schedules": [
    {
      "days": [
        "Wed",
        "Fri"
      ],
      "start": "2022-01-07T13:30:00.859Z",
      "end": "2022-01-07T14:30:00.859Z"
    },
    {
      "days": [
        "Mon"
      ],
      "start": "2022-01-10T13:30:00.859Z",
      "end": "2022-01-12T14:30:00.859Z"
    }
  ]
}]
```

While outside those hours the result should be this:

```js
[{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "schedules": [
    {
      "days": [
        "Tue",
        "Wed",
        "Fri"
      ],
      "start": "2022-01-07T10:50:00.859Z",
      "end": "2022-01-07T11:30:00.859Z"
    },
    {
      "days": [
        "Mon"
      ],
      "start": "2022-01-10T13:30:00.859Z",
      "end": "2022-01-12T14:30:00.859Z"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "firstName": "Aaron",
  "lastName": "Park",
  "schedules": [
    {
      "days": [
        "Wed",
        "Fri"
      ],
      "start": "2022-01-07T13:30:00.859Z",
      "end": "2022-01-07T14:30:00.859Z"
    },
    {
      "days": [
        "Mon"
      ],
      "start": "2022-01-10T13:30:00.859Z",
      "end": "2022-01-12T14:30:00.859Z"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: Please provide an expected output.

Comment: I will edit the question and add it.

Comment: You seem to be comparing the day as well in the if condition. `if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime)` - here you should compare only the time component and ignore the date. `startTime`, `endTime` includes date as well as the time

Comment: Your code return an user in the final result if the current day of the week is contained in the `days` array and the current time isn't in the time interval.  It isn't clear if that was your aim

Comment: Sorry if I can't be very clear, I updated the question with some topics that I would like to take into account with the final result.

Comment: One problem was that in cyberpirate answer, namely you compare the dates not only times, but again you stated "not be returned if the current date is not in the timestamps" and this affermation comprehends dates too

Comment: First I see what day of the week it is, if it is not in the array the user is returned, if the day of the week is in the array I will only want users whose current time is not within the time range of start and end (in these two timestamps I only care about hours and minutes).

Comment: Ok, you had not specified this before. Then you have to use @cyberpirate92 's solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method like this to ignore the date and just compare the times.

```js
function fallsInInterval(start, end, date) {
    const now = new Date();
    const s = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), start.getHours(), start.getMinutes(), start.getSeconds());
    const e = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), end.getHours(), end.getMinutes(), end.getSeconds());
    const d = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds());
    return d >= s && d <= e;
}
```

All the above method does is to create new date objects where the date component is the same for all but the original time is preserved, which makes the comparison easier.

So, instead of

```js
if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) {
    return false;
}
```

you will use

```js
if (fallsInInterval(startTime, endTime, currentTime)) {
    return false;
}
```